# Convert DateTime (TimePart) to a readable days, hours and minutes based on a day hour

Tags: c#

I have a code in c# and I need to accumulate all the hours in a DateTime format.

I have a foreach statement where I calculate pending hours but that pending hours need to be accumulated so at the end I have a total of hours and minutes and based on a day limit hours for example my day could be a 8 hours day, then I can format it as string like the following example:

If my total hours is: 24 hours 31 minutes then based on a 8 hour day I should format as follows:

```
3 days, 31 minutes.
```

I need to know the best way to accumulate the hours, here is the code that is inside my foreach:

```
// here I create a Timespan in order to get hours and minutes from a DB.
 var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(double.Parse(drItem["PayableHours"].ToString()));
                            int hh = timeSpan.Hours;
                            int mm = timeSpan.Minutes;
                            int ss = timeSpan.Seconds;


                            // pending hours
// here i create a tempHours variable for a 8 hour 
                            DateTime tempHours = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0);
// here I substract from my 8 hour datetime the hours and the minutes of my timespan
                            DateTime pendingHours = dayHours.Add(new TimeSpan(-hh,-mm,0));

// here i should accumulate the pendingHours so when the foreach statement finish I can format the total hours and minutes to string.
```

Any clue?

Comment: why even convert to a datetime? wouldn't keeping it as a timespan work best?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it would look something like this:

```
private static string PrettyPrint(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var parts = new List<string>();

    int totalHours = (int)timeSpan.TotalHours;
    int workDays = totalHours / 8;
    int remainingHours = (int)timeSpan.TotalHours - 8 * workDays;

    if (workDays == 1) parts.Add("1 day");
    if (workDays > 1) parts.Add(workDays + " days");

    if (remainingHours == 1) parts.Add("1 hour");
    if (remainingHours > 1) parts.Add(timeSpan.Hours + " hours");

    if (timeSpan.Minutes == 1) parts.Add("1 minute");
    if (timeSpan.Minutes > 1) parts.Add(timeSpan.Minutes + " minutes");

    return string.Join(", ", parts);
}
```

You might want to also add some code to check for TimeSpan.Zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then:

```
int numberDays = hh / 8;
```

will give you the number of days.  From there, the rest should be easy.